# React router does not render route when URL accessed directly

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Consider this the main App component (imports left out for brevity):

```js
const App = () => {
    const [orderRoutes, setOrderRoutes] = useState([])

    const updateOrderRoutes = (newRoute) => {
        orderRoutes.push(newRoute)
        setOrderRoutes(orderRoutes)
    }

    const renderedOrderRoutes = orderRoutes.map(route => {
        return (
            <Route
                path={`/${route.class}/${route.order}`}
                exact
                key={`/${route.class}/${route.order}`}
            >
                <CatalogPage />
            </Route>
        )
    })

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Header
                updateOrderRoutes={updateOrderRoutes}
            />
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/aboutus" exact component={AboutUs} />
            <Route path="/faq" exact component={Faq} />
            <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} />
            {renderedOrderRoutes}
            <Footer />
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default App
```

The challenge is that some of the routes are not known when rendering the initial App component. They will be known when an AJAX request in the `<Header>` component is responded to. The header will then update the new route to the `orderRoutes` state property, re-rendering the `App` component every time. The routes that are the result of the AJAX call (that is made in the `<Header>`) are then rendered to the `<BrowserRouter>` (in `{renderedOrderRoutes}`). In the `<Header>`, there is a `<Link>` for each route being rendered as a result of the same AJAX call, so that every menu entry (The `<Link>`s) will have a corresponding route.

This works fine, but when I access one of the URL's that this mechanism generates directly (e.g.: refresh the page), the `<CatalogPage>` component is not rendered.

So, for instance let's say that the AJAX call results in a bunch of routes and one of those is `/t-shirts/tanktops`. I will get a menu entry with a link to that path. When I click that menu entry the `<CatalogPage>` component is rendered. But when I access `/t-shirts/tanktops` directly, the `<CatalogPage>` component is not rendered.

How can I alter this code to make the URL's that are a result of the AJAX call directly accessible?

**EDIT**

OK, I 'solved' this (don't like it) by forcing the `<App>` component to re-render when one of the `<Link>s` was clicked by creating an unused piece of state on the `App` component called `activeOrderRoute`. I passed the setter down to the `Header` as a prop and connected it as a callback to the `onClick` handler for each `Link` that was created in response to the AJAX request. This essentially forces the `App` to re-render and render the routes, which solved my problems.

Still, that does not seem like the correct way to do it so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've answered blow how you can handle rendering accessible routes, but it seems you've also an odd workaround between your `App` and `Header` components to kick one or both of them to rerender to display links to the "new" routes. Can you update your question to include the route fetching logic and the relevant parts of both `App` and `Header`?

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27928372/470749

Answer (score 2):

you need to modify your webpack.config.js and add the following lines.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  ...
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with webpack config but does this only set this option when compiling for development?

Answer (score 1):

React router does not directly have routing support for all URLs. It catches the default domain only the remaining routing is done on client side and requests are not served.
If your domain is [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), you can not access the URL [www.mydomain.com/info](http://www.mydomain.com/info) directly in the react router.
Solutions:

1. You can use a hash router but that makes the URLs unfriendly for SEO
2. You can set up a catch-all routes and route it yourself

This link would help you with the same
https://ui.dev/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean by 'requests are not served'?

Comment: Basically your server does not know that the route www.mydomain.com/info even exists, it's known only to the client side react code with react router. So when any user makes a request to www.mydomain.com/info, they won't get the response expected(they won't get served). your server only resolves the homepage/index page of the react app

Comment: I understand that. I use the path (so in your example: '/info') to render the correct component in the router path **and** to get the argument to perform the AJAX request. I then update the state of the `<CatalogPage>` component to re-render it with the fetched information. The problem is, is that I need to force-update the re-rendering of the `<App>` component, but maybe this is a normal workflow in React?

Comment: This is a normal workflow yup, it's also how most fetch requests work so this is not an issue and component re-rendering is honestly not that heavy for react but keep in mind that you do not update any of these in use functions to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: OK, I think I need a paradigm shift. I was trying to avoid rerendering as much as possible but you're right: it isn't that much of an intensive operation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to explicitly render a route for each asynchronously fetched route, leverage the power of react-router-dom and render a dynamic route [path string](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string) that can handle any catalog page.

Instead of this:

```
const renderedOrderRoutes = orderRoutes.map(route => {
  return (
    <Route
      path={`/${route.class}/${route.order}`}
      exact
      key={`/${route.class}/${route.order}`}
    >
      <CatalogPage />
    </Route>
  )
})

return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Header
      updateOrderRoutes={updateOrderRoutes}
    />
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/aboutus" exact component={AboutUs} />
    <Route path="/faq" exact component={Faq} />
    <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} />
    {renderedOrderRoutes}
    <Footer />
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Render a single dynamic route in your `Router`. Use a `Switch` so only a single route component is matched and rendered. Reorder the routes so the more specific paths can be matched ***before*** less specific paths. Now, when a URL has a path that is of the shape `"/someClass/someOrder"` it can be matched before you try matching any of the more general paths. You will see that the home path (`"/"`) is matched last and the reordering allows us to remove the `exact` prop on all routes.

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Header updateOrderRoutes={updateOrderRoutes} />
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/:class/:order"
        exact
        component={CatalogPage}
      />
      <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
      <Route path="/faq" component={Faq} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

You may need to adjust some logic in `CatalogPage` to handle possible undefined catalog data, whatever it is using from the route props/etc... to render catalog stuff.

In your `Header` component make the asynchronous call there to fetch the routes that can be navigated to so you can dynamically render render links to them (*if that is even why you are passing the routes to `Header`*).

Comment: Really helpful. Need to update my react-router mastery. Good tips, thanks

Comment: @GuidoGoluke Does this answer help to at least partly resolve your issue? I suspect there is more we could do with the interplay between `App` and `Header`. If you wanted to add more example code to your question we can try to completely resolve your issue.

Comment: I've got the interplay between App and Header down, just passing the `useState` setters down as props and triggering a rerender of App did the trick. I think I need to have a better understanding of what React Router can and cannot do and how it has already solved caveats. I just don't know enough about that.

I do wonder why some 'Link' components don't trigger rerenders, but I think that falls in the same category. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, links don't directly update state and/or props, but depending on route setups and what is matched can change what is being rendered. When rendering dynamic paths and you simply go from one match param to another, i.e. like just going to a different id, then the rendered component doesn't remount, so it needs to handle the updated param from props/routing context if it needs to rerender with different data/ui/etc.

Comment: Thanks for all you assistance. I have some homework to do!